# Асинхронная отправка файлов на сервер .Net MVC

Tags: c#, html, .net, mvc

Всем доброго времени суток. Вопрос следующий: мне нужно асинхронно отправить на сервер несколько фотографий, там сохранить их в директории сервер и вернуть клиенту эти же фотографии. Проблема в том, что `Ajax.BeginForm()` не подходит для асинхронной передачи файлов, вот мой вопрос на этот счет: ["Клик"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864294/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-ajax-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-net-mvc). 
  Подскажите, как это сделать? Вот моя форма, которая отправляет данные **не асинхронно**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PhotoSessionInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <span>Название фотосесии (будет отображаться в галереи): </span>
    <br />

    @Html.TextBox("sessionName", null, new { @class = "sessionName" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Выберите изображение, которое будет являться заставкой фотосесии:  </span>
    <br />
    <div id="dropZoneForGeneral">
        Перетащите файл сюда или  <input value="выберите файл" id="GeneralPhoto" type="file" name="generalPhoto" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Выберите изображения: </span>
    <br />
    <div id="dropZone">
        Перетащите файл сюда или <input value="выберите файлы" multiple type="file" name="photos" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit"> Отправить </button>
}
```

Comment: Я ответа не знаю, но вот что гуглится первым https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: 1. Кто вам сказал, что Ajax.BeginForm не подходит?

Comment: 2. Почему вы не хотите использовать jquery или просто javascript?

Comment: Потому что я уже задавал вопрос про Ajax.BeginForm и там сказали, что нельзя передать файл таким способом